# mkarchiso doesnt create an iso without any error

Tags: linux, arch-linux, iso-image

I'm trying to create a custom Archiso with only the linux-lts kernel and KDE-Plasma as desktop.

But when I run `mkarchiso`, it doesnt create a iso nor compress the build, like it normally would.
These are the last lines of mkarchiso:

```
(17/29) fix appstream datas for pamac
(18/29) Updating fontconfig cache...
(19/29) Probing GDK-Pixbuf loader modules...
(20/29) Updating GIO module cache...
(21/29) Compiling GSettings XML schema files...
(22/29) Probing GTK3 input method modules...
(23/29) Updating icon theme caches...
(24/29) Updating the info directory file...
(25/29) Uncommenting all mirrors in /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist...
(26/29) Updating the desktop file MIME type cache...
(27/29) Updating the vlc plugin cache...
(28/29) Updating X fontdir indices...
(29/29) Work around FS#49347 by removing custom pacman hooks that are only required during ISO build...
[mkarchiso] INFO: Done! Packages installed successfully.
[mkarchiso] INFO: Creating version files...
[mkarchiso] INFO: Done!
[mkarchiso] INFO: Copying /etc/skel/* to user homes...
(END)
```

If you need some (config) files, please let me know.

**Edit:** I have found out, that when i use a normal releng profile, with linux-lts then it creates the iso perfectly. So my theory is, that i have put so much files in the archlive folder, that it doesn't want to create the iso anymore.